# Built-in php linter not reporting errors

Tags: php, macos

I'm having trouble getting php -l(the built in linter) to actually recognize that the file it's linting has issues.  I'm on Mac OS X Lion, running php 5.3.8.  I verified through the command line (php -i) that display_errors is set to On and error_reporting is set to E_ALL | E_STRICT.

Here is my test file, I've tried others with the same result:

```
<?php
abcde
for {
?>
```

running that through php -l nets the response:

> No syntax errors detected in test.php

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you edited correct php.ini? Confirm it with `phpinfo()`

Comment: that is usually the case. You set it correct and it should work. Are you 100% sure you are accessing the file you think you do? I mean if you remove the error and put "echo 123;" will that print it? I guess you checked it with phpinfo() but it's worth asking.